How to get the integral symbol exactly like below?


This integral sign looks like the one from Cambria Math, but it is thinner. File pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14kTXjVH32yQlsZksSduFr9XpbglbPPeE/view?usp=sharing
I tried using \resizebox and \scalebox, but the result doesn't look as good as in the picture, both ends of it are a bit small.
This is the result when I use \resizebox

\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\resizebox' macro
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} 

\DeclareMathOperator{\intg}{%
   \resizebox{0.7\width}{\height}{$\displaystyle\int$}} 

\begin{document} 
\[ 
\int  \quad 
\intg \quad 
\mathop{\intg}_{0}^{2} e^{x}\symrm{d}x 
\]
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not show your used code as image, we con not copy and paste for testing on our computers ...

Not related, but Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?

I've taken the liberty of simplifying your LaTeX code. Feel free to revert.

I think it looks just like cambria, but difficult to see with that image. Maybe different rendings. Or maybe they use one of the available sizes scaled down. What disturbs more is the weird location of the limits. Where did you find this?

This integral symbol was in my country's high school graduation exam.

@thanhlam5150 If you have a pdf of the exam, then checking the embedded fonts in the pdf would be useful.

Only 2 fonts: Math font: Cambria Math, Main font: Times New Roman

@thanhlam5150 Sorry for the late response. I did not get your comment notification. Can you share the pdf with me? I am interested.

@Apoorv Potnis https://drive.google.com/file/d/14kTXjVH32yQlsZksSduFr9XpbglbPPeE/view?usp=sharing
